# image map not working, could this be because of the image size?

Tags: html

```css
.container {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.container>div {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 1200px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="intro">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1913x6360" alt="" usemap="article">
    <map name="article">
                <area shape="poly" coords="13.81, 154.51, 20.00, 154.55, 20.00, 156.51, 12.70, 156.51" href="#" alt="">
                <area shape="poly" coords="12.27, 170.0, 18.41, 170.0, 18.41, 170.0, 11.16, 170.0" href="#" alt="">
            </map>
  </div>
</div>
```

The image map is not working and I have no idea why this isn't working. Could it possibly be because I set the image size to be 1500px while the actual image size is 1913px?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working due to the `GET https://placehold.it/1913x6360 net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID` error in the console, usually that means there's a difference between your computer's time and the validity of the website's SSL certificate.

1. You are also missing the `#` in `usemap="#article"`.
2. Using a simpler shape and coords makes the shape easier to notice, for example `<area shape="rect" coords="34, 44, 270, 350" href="#" alt="">`.
3. Try a different placeholder image, like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.container>div {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 1200px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="intro">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ARC2saC.png" alt="" usemap="#article">
    <map name="article">
                <area shape="rect" coords="34, 44, 270, 350" href="#" alt="">
                <area shape="poly" coords="12.27, 170.0, 18.41, 170.0, 18.41, 170.0, 11.16, 170.0" href="#" alt="">
            </map>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh I didn't use the placeholder image, the actual image is on the server and on my hard drive; I just replace that with the placeholdit to not reveal the personal info on the internet. So you're saying that the code itself is fine and should be working if there was no problem otherwise?

Comment: Upon closer inspection, you were also missing the `#` in `usemap="#article"`

Comment: Thank you. It still didn't work for some unknown reason so I just patched the issue up by using css positions...